# Tracking deselecting radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to track when a radio element gets deselected?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $('#answer-1').change(function(){
        console.log('radio-1 changed');
    });

    $('#answer-2').change(function(){
        console.log('radio-2 changed');
    });

});
</script> 

<input name="question-1" type="radio" id="answer-1" />Value
<input name="question-1" type="radio" id="answer-2" />Value
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wZ73z/)

Expected result: When selecting answer-1, it shows event 'radio-1 changed', then when switching to answer-2, it **should** show radio-2 changed AND radio-1 changed

Actual result: When selecting answer-1, it shows event 'radio-1 changed', then when switching to answer-2, it shows only 'radio-2 changed'

Is there a way to get events when the radio's get DEselected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.data`

here is the fiddle that may help http://jsfiddle.net/wZ73z/19/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $('input[name=question-1]').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
          console.log('radio is selected');
        else
          console.log('radio is note selected');
    });
});
</script>
```